# How to store singular dynamic values in a Django web application?

Tags: python, django

In [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) when I want to store models like users, places and so on I may use an SQL database, but when I want to store a particular value (only one) I have no idea what to use.

So, I'm doing a website where there is some information that changes monthly. Giving one example:

```
<meta name="description" content="This team is in {{ ranking }} in the world ranking">
```

I'll need to change that value, ideally from Django Admin monthly and a Model with one object seems too much (not too much work but simply too much).

I started looking at NoSQL and from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3554169/4470542) I'm inclined to use [Redis](http://redis.io/) or a similar key-value DB.

Is it the right approach or am I completely off track?

Comment: SQLite gives you room to grow and is super-lightweight (as the name implies) This is really kind of a question likely to attract opinion-based answers, though.

Comment: "a Model with one object seems too much (not too much work but simply too much)." I don't see why it is. You create it, it stores a tiny bit in your database and that's it; it won't exhaust your disk space or anything. You're overthinking it; just keep it simple and use what you know.

Comment: in addition to the comment of @Evert I'd like to add that writing a simple key value store model is done quicker than writing this question.

Comment: A key-value table, cached in redis is more than enough!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think for this case it better to use existing solutions like [Constance - Dynamic Django settings](http://django-constance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). It is general solution for modifiable variables through django admin interface.

Here is list of similar apps https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/live-setting/

Answer (score 2):

You could use [python's shelve](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/shelve.html) for a simple out-of-the-box solution for object persistence. It's easy to use:

```
with shelve.open('my_store') as my_store:
    my_store['ranking'] = 10
```

and then:

```
with shelve.open('my_store') as my_store:
    ranking = my_store['ranking']
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the solution but it only fits some cases so I accepted the other answer. For ex: It wouldn't work with replication of servers.